# Git: How to Rebase Squash without having multiple conflict resolution

Tags: git

Let's say I've branched off `master`. This branch is called `spaghetti`. On my new `spaghetti` branch the last commit is perfect.

How can I create one new commit after `master` with all files in the exact state as my last commit on `spaghetti`. I don't want to have any conflict resolution.

When I tried `rebase -i` I would get prompt after prompt of "Which value should I take". Ideally I would just `rebase -i` telling it to take everything from my last commit somehow?

How can I do this?

Also would a regular rebase work? Pluck off that node and place it after master?

Comment: `git rebase -i` literally means interactive, so having it not prompt you is not realistic.

Comment: Fair point lol!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take your last revision *as is* and make it the content of a new revision of top of another branch (you just don't care about what was going on on the other branch), then this is what you do:

`git checkout master
git checkout spaghetti .
git commit -m "we look just like spaghetti"`

Careful **not** to leave the dot out when doing the checkout.

This is not something to do lightly because you will basically revert everything you did on master after it diverged from spaghetti.

Another way (by the way), and perhaps a little more elegant:

`git checkout --detach spaghetti
git reset --soft master
git commit -m "Committing what we have at the tip of spaghetti on master"
git branch -f master # repoint master
git checkout master`

Comment: *revert everything you did on master* Don't worry too much — at any moment you can do `git checkout master~ .` or `git reset [--hard] master~` or `git revert`.

Comment: Right this makes sense. I never thought of a checkout and a `.`